# Building a grid of real estate which can be sorted and filtered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question in regards to creating a grid in HTML, CSS and Javascript which can be sorted from highest to lowest and vice versa. You should also be able to filter.

Right now i am doing a grid using bootstrap. When googling i can see that many use unordered lists ul in order to do so. My question is, can you make a grid which is actually a ul?

This is the code i have made to begin with:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      
        <div class="filter">
          <h1>Boliger</h1>
          <button>Pris, Faldende</button>
          <button>Pris, Stigende</button>
        </div>
        <div class="properties">
        <ul>
            <div class="row">
          
          <li>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="property" data-id="01">
              <img
                class="property__image image-fluid"
                src="assets/01.jpg"
                alt=""
              />
              <h2 class="property__title">Lige ud til vejen</h2>
              <p class="property__address">
                Dommervænget 6a, 2. th, 4000 Roskilde
              </p>
              <ul class="property__info">
                <li class="property__price">1.000.000,-</li>
                <li class="property__type">Villa</li>
                <li class="property__rooms">4 Rum</li>
                <li class="property__size">120 m2</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          </li>
          <li><div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="property" data-id="02">
              <img class="property__image" src="assets/02.jpg" alt="" />
              <h2 class="property__title">Rustikt og lækkert</h2>
              <p class="property__address">
                Enghavevej 8, 1. th, 1674 København V
              </p>
              <ul class="property__info">
                <li class="property__price">2.500.000,-</li>
                <li class="property__type">Ejerlejlighed</li>
                <li class="property__rooms">2 Rum</li>
                <li class="property__size">80 m2</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: by setting the row directly to ul and col in li. which bootstrap version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, if you want to see it with snippet for sure, make full screen as you were setting `.col-sm-6`

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="filter">
      <h1>Boliger</h1>
      <button>Pris, Faldende</button>
      <button>Pris, Stigende</button>
    </div>
    <div class="properties">
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="property" data-id="01">
            <img
              class="property__image image-fluid"
              src="assets/01.jpg"
              alt=""
            />
            <h2 class="property__title">Lige ud til vejen</h2>
            <p class="property__address">
              Dommervænget 6a, 2. th, 4000 Roskilde
            </p>
            <ul class="property__info">
              <li class="property__price">1.000.000,-</li>
              <li class="property__type">Villa</li>
              <li class="property__rooms">4 Rum</li>
              <li class="property__size">120 m2</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="property" data-id="02">
            <img class="property__image" src="assets/02.jpg" alt="" />
            <h2 class="property__title">Rustikt og lækkert</h2>
            <p class="property__address">
              Enghavevej 8, 1. th, 1674 København V
            </p>
            <ul class="property__info">
              <li class="property__price">2.500.000,-</li>
              <li class="property__type">Ejerlejlighed</li>
              <li class="property__rooms">2 Rum</li>
              <li class="property__size">80 m2</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try that out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Flexbox Layout** to display the grid, as its name suggests its flexible
and we can control the flow of the grid contents efficiently.
I suggest you to learn/use vue.js unless you want to code everything- sorting, then displaying the result, aquiring/updating data etc. in vanilla js. Also by browsing through these topics - **css flexbox, css-grid, vue.js** (generally **single page app development**), atleast you will gain some insight into solving the above mentioned problem.

Comment: Thank you, i'll definitely check it out!